# jquery rotate image onclick

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve this (90 degree rotation), but it fails without errors.
This image is within a `<a></a>` TAG where it has already a toggle jquery function.

```
<?php echo "<img src='down_arrow.png' onclick='$(this).animate({rotate: \"+=90deg\"});' />"; ?>
```

Comment: you need a plugin for rotation , you knew that right ? and dont show us the serverside code , the generated html is enough.

Comment: You are using [this](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html) patch?

Comment: No I thought it was included in jquery :s
i will check this out,

Thank you

Comment: @mpm Gee, if he knew he needed a plugin, reckon he'd be asking on SO?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider a jQuery extension such as: [jQueryRotate](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/)

It'll make the rotating inside the onclick much easier and more readable.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The image rotates only once : `onclick='$(this).rotate(180);'`

Comment: Is that a comment or a question?

Comment: You need to do a variable rotation, off the top of my head I don't know how to get the item's rotation, but in psuedocode it'd be something like `onclick='$(this).rotate(180);'`

Comment: Sorry, please update to the following link:  https://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Comment: still rotating only once

Answer (score 47):

Depending on which browser versions you need to support, you could try CSS tranforms.

First, define a CSS class like this:

```
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
}
```

And then you can use jQuery to add the class when clicking the link:

```
<img src="down_arrow.png" onclick="$(this).addClass('rotated');" />
```

Comment: It's simply amazing how much one can accomplish when we simply know when to add a class or an id to an element via jquery

Answer (score 22):

Use a combination of css rules `-webkit-transform` and `-moz-transform` on image click.For example to rotate image by 90 degree apply following css rules on click

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
        "transform": "rotate(90deg)" /* For modern browsers(CSS3)  */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

This will enable you to perform an additional rotation of each clik

```
var degrees = 0;
$('.img').click(function rotateMe(e) {

    degrees += 90;

    //$('.img').addClass('rotated'); // for one time rotation

    $('.img').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
    }); 

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnckq5om/1/

Comment: Wonderful solution. Very clear what to do by following the jsfiddle. In my case it was exactly what the doctor ordered. A big thanks!

Comment: Missing some closing brackets

Answer (score 7):

checkout this:  [**JqueryRotate**](http://jqueryrotate.com/)

this have little things to do, you can see one code example in the image itself.

[image]

So in your case you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img[src^="down_arrow"]').click(function(){
      $(this).rotate(90);
   });
});
```

Comment: Why is that my code works only once ? 
`onclick='$(this).rotate(180);'`

The image is rotated but if i click again it doest

Comment: @ArtPlanteur Probably because you're already rotated at 180 degrees.

Comment: how would you save the rotated image then ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the example to rotate image 90deg as following code bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
         $(this).rotate(90);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answers above and created a method to do incremental rotation, by storing the current rotation in a data attribute on the target element. In other words, every time you call the function, it will add to the existing rotation.

```
// Increments the rotation (in degrees) for the element with the given id
function addRotation(id, degrees) {
    var control = $('#' + id);
    var currentRotation = control.data('rotation');
    if (typeof currentRotation === 'undefined') currentRotation = 0;

    degrees += parseInt(currentRotation);

    control.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
    });

    control.data('rotation', degrees);
}
```

Usage:

```
<img id='my-image' />

addRotation('my-image', 90);
addRotation('my-image', -90);
```

Answer (score 0):

I very much liked @Savage's answer above. I wanted to be able to just add a class to an element to make any image with that class rotatable. Also wanted to have it rotate to the right (clockwise) when I clicked on the right side and on the left (counter-clockwise) when I clicked on the left.

Here is where I'm hooking up the click events ([from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785504/how-to-know-if-user-clicks-in-the-left-of-an-image-or-in-the-right)) - I do use jQuery on the page so forgive me that indulgence - but this gives you the correct rotation based upon where on the image you've clicked:

```
        $('.tot-rotatable-image').on('click', function (e) {
            var elm = $(this);
            var xPos = e.pageX - elm.offset().left;

            if((elm.width() / 2) >= xPos){
                addRotation(e, -90);
            } else {
                addRotation(e, 90);
            }
        });
```

And here's a slightly modified version of addRotation that just takes the event rather than a selector. This works particularly nicely with the approach that @Savage went with related to attaching the current rotation to the DOM element.

```
        function addRotation(evt, degrees) {
            var control = $(evt.currentTarget);
            var currentRotation = parseInt(control.data('rotation'));
            degrees += isNaN(currentRotation) ? 0 : currentRotation;

            control.css({
                'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
            });

            control.data('rotation', degrees);
        }
```

I do have some styling issues related to where images overlap each other but still I'm overall pleased at how this can be sprinkled about quickly and easily.