# rotate image on click

Tags: jquery, css

I want to rotate the **image** when I click in the span.

So jquery needs to call css effect on click... but nothing is happening. what is wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/cc4tg1b7/1/

html

```
<span class='l'>
    <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png'>
    rotate image on click
</span>
```

css

```
.l img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.li img {
    animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".l", function () {

        $('.l img').toggleClass(".li img");

    });
});
```

Comment: Google brought me back to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365449/jquery-rotate-image-onclick

Comment: you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a slight mistake in your css definition and the use of toggleClass.

Here is the JS code.

```
$('.l img').toggleClass("spin");
```

CSS

```
.l img{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}
.l img.spin{
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
```

[see it in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x4ztz56/)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this inside your click function

`$(this).toggleClass("li");`

According to your CSS rule written,  the image will rotate if its wrapper span has the class `li`

Also use `$(this)` to make sure that you rotate only the clicked image and not all the images.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc4tg1b7/3/)**

Comment: @RickJoe like this https://jsfiddle.net/cc4tg1b7/3/ :) just had a extra `.` next to li removing it ges your result

Comment: @RickJoe this will also work but you have written as $(this).toggleClass(".li"); here toggleClass() method refers to class oly not ID selector or any other so there you have added ".li" just remove dot it will work

Comment: @RickJoe also see this https://jsfiddle.net/6x4ztz56/2/ to know what issues you might face. And see this https://jsfiddle.net/cc4tg1b7/4/ to know how it solves. And then decide which suits better for you :)

Answer (score 1):

small changed need to be make in your code where you have written css as .li img {...} here you need to remove img and in jquery as well at toggleClass

```js
$( document ).on( "click", "img", function() {
$('.l img').toggleClass("li");

});
```

```css
.l img{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}
.li{
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='l'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png'>rotate image on click</span>
```