# How to know if user clicks in the left of an image or in the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" class=imgclick>
```

I have a gallery and I'd like to know if user click on the left of the image to show the image before or if he clicks on the right to show next one.

I tried:

```
$('.imgclick').click(function (e){

    var elm = $(this);
    var xPos = e.pageX - elm.offset().left;

    var total = e.pageX;

    if((total / 2) <= xPos){
        alert("left");
    }
    else{
        alert("right");
    }

});
```

but it is only returning "left", any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Calculation needs to be based on width of image also. Draw this out on a piece of paper and mark what `offset()` gives you, what `e.pageX` gives you etc then creating formula should be easy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685708/determining-if-mouse-click-happened-in-left-or-right-half-of-div

Answer (score 1):

You need to check from half the size of the image width `elm.width()`

```js
$('.imgclick').click(function (e){

    var elm = $(this);
    var xPos = e.pageX - elm.offset().left;

    if((elm.width() / 2) >= xPos){
        alert("left");
    } else {
        alert("right");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" class=imgclick>
```

But, read further to see how most developers create a gallery. It's as simple as putting an overlay (see orange and green transparent overlay), over the image(s). At the end, you remove the colors and no one will see that he clicks on a completely transparent element...

```js
$('.gallery [data-gallery-control]').on('click', function(){
  alert($(this).data('gallery-control'));
  // move on from here if "right" or if "left"
  // do what ever you need
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.gallery img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery [data-gallery-control] {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.5;

}

.gallery [data-gallery-control="right"] {
  right: 0;
}

.gallery [data-gallery-control="left"] {
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" class=imgclick>
<a data-gallery-control="right" href="#path-to-next-image">right</a>
<a data-gallery-control="left" href="#path-to-prev-image">left</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the x position and then check if its less than half of width of image.

```
$(".imgclick").on("click", function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    alert(x < this.width / 2 ? 'Left' : 'Right');
});
```